# How to use xpath or lxml to get a specific xsd element data(namespace includes)?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, lxml

I am having a problem to reach `vc:minVersion`  from xsd file.

Part of xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="lbs"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    rb:version="0.2"
    vc:minVersion="1.1"
>

  <!-- main -->
  <xs:element name="lbs">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="header">
```

My code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
dom = ET.parse(u'/lbs.xsd')
rootxml = dom.getroot()
nss = rootxml.nsmap
for subtag in rootxml.xpath(u'//minVersion', namespaces=nss):
    #do something
    print(subtag)
```

Code shows nothing, when I expect to get "1.1" as answer. Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If namespaces are used it should be

```
//@vc:minVersion
```

Ignoring namespaces it would be

```
//@*[local-name()="minVersion"]
```

Comment: Omg it worked, I was so close. Thanks a lot! I spend so much time trying to figure this out.